# cat reading from an array of files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am collecting some tsv files on a daily basis in the directory structure that looks like /tmp/data/$yearmonth/$day/$hour.  So there are 24 directories inside of /tmp/data/$yearmonth/$day

I have shell script like this:

```
yearmonth=`date -d "-2 days" +%Y%m`
day=`date -d "-2 days" +%d`

files=()
cd /tmp/data/$yearmonth/$day
for i in `ls -a */*.tsv`
do
  files+=($i)
done
```

The array files has all the tsv files stored in it.  I want to "cat" all these tsvfiles to one single tsvfiles and want to perform sort|uniq -c on it.
How do I do that? 
As the tsv files become huge cat can get very slow.  What could be the other alternative.
Thanks

Comment: What's slow about the `cat`?

Comment: The tsv files are really huge and cat operation is being very slow

Comment: Can you show all of the code?

Comment: When you say that `cat` is really slow, it sounds like you mean that it's really slow to read all of the files; but you're saying that what you need to do is, read all of the files . . .

Comment: BTW, `cat` is usually not really needed. For example, in this case `sort` also accepts a list of filenames, so you can just write `sort $(ls -a /tmp/data/$yearmonth/$day/*/*.tsv) | uniq -c`. (But this doesn't buy you very much, because I'm sure `cat` itself is not actually your bottleneck.)

Comment: Thanks but I want to do other operations too like cut -f 1, 4|uniq -c on the merged file.

Comment: @ruak:  I mean I dont want to create an intermediate file that has the contents of all tsv files; I also want to operations like cut, uniq on it.

Comment: @user1189851: `cat` doesn't create an intermediate file, it just writes to standard output. Are you saying that you're redirecting its output to a file, and then having `sort` read from that file? If so, the easiest fix is just to *not* do that. :-P You're obviously already familiar with pipes; use one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues with the code you are showing:

1. If you have enough files or the names are long enough in your subdirs `ls -a` is going to fail with too many files in the argument list. The standard remedy is to use `find`

   find /tmp/data/year/mon/day -type f -iname '*.tsv' -print0
2. Once you have find you can pipe the file list it generates directly into sort

   | xargs -0 sort --unique

No `cat` involved, but of course, the files still need to be found and read.